# Is it decidable to determine if a given shape can tile the plane?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, decidability, undecidability

I know that it is undecidable to determine if a set of tiles can tile the plane,
a result of Berger using [Wang tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile).
My question is whether it is also known to be undecidable to determine
if a *single* given tile can tile the plane, a *monohedral* tiling.

If this remains unsettled, I would be interested to know what is the minimum
cardinality of a set of tiles for which there is an undecidability proof.
(I have not yet accessed Berger's proof.)

Comment: Another recent undecidability proof can be found in: Nicolas Ollinger; [Two-by-two Substitution Systems and the Undecidability of the Domino Problem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-69407-6_51); Logic and Theory of Algorithms, 4th Conference on Computability in Europe, CiE 2008 ([pdf](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/260112/filename/sutica.pdf)) ... but they use more tiles (104) to build an aperiodic tileset (Robinson's proof uses 56 tiles)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the introduction of [1],

- The complexity of determining if a single polyomino tiles the plane remains open [2,3], and
- There is an undecidability proof for sets of 5 polyominoes [4].

[1] Stefan Langerman, Andrew Winslow. [A Quasilinear-Time Algorithm for Tiling the Plane Isohedrally with a Polyomino](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02762). ArXiv e-prints, 2015. arXiv:1507.02762 [cs.CG]

[2] C. Goodman-Strauss. [Open questions in tiling](http://comp.uark.edu/~strauss/papers/survey.pdf). Online, published 2000.

[3] C. Goodman-Strauss. [Can’t decide? undecide!](http://www.ams.org/notices/201003/rtx100300343p.pdf) Notices of the American
Mathematical Society, 57(3):343–356, 2010.

[4] N. Ollinger. [Tiling the plane with a fixed number of polyominoes](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00335781/document). In
A. H. Dediu, A. M. Ionescu, and C. Mart´ın-Vide, editors, LATA 2009,
volume 5457 of LNCS, pages 638–647. Springer, 2009.

Answer (score 14):

An extended comment: a recent paper by Demaine & al. proves that one tile is enough to simulate an arbitrary computation:

Erik D. Demaine, Martin L. Demaine, Sándor P. Fekete, Matthew J. Patitz, Robert T. Schweller, Andrew Winslow, Damien Woods; [One Tile to Rule Them All: Simulating Any Turing Machine, Tile Assembly System, or Tiling System with a Single Puzzle Piece](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4756) (2012)

**but** the tiling is not an exact tiling : *"... The output one-tile system requires tiles to live on the same square or hexagonal lattice, allows tiles to rotate, and is **nearly plane** tiling in the sense that it leaves tiny gaps between the tiles. ..."*

Comment: Nice, that is the fastest answer.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: Some time ago, I gave a quick look at the paper but I forgot that the tiling is not exact ... I modified the answer ... :-)